# Bad event on java panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a java panel with 4 buttons. When I click on of these buttons, a new frame appears and the first is hidden with `setVisibile(false)`.
On that new window, I have another button, but when i click it, I got the event corresponding to the fourth button of the first window. Clicking the button again does the trick, but of course this is not acceptable.
Am I missing something? I just show the frames with

```
nameOfTheFrame.setVisible(true);
```

and I have MouseListeners on every button.

The code of the last button is simply:

```
System.exit(0);
```

EDIT

Sample code:

```
    private void btn_joinGamePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            GraphicsTools.getInstance().getCreateGame().setVisible(false);
            GraphicsTools.getInstance().getMainPanel().setVisible(false);
            GraphicsTools.getInstance().getRegistration().setVisible(true);
}
```

GraphicsTools is a Singleton.

EDIT 2
Some more informations.
I noticed that on MAC OS works fine. The problem happens only on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Could you post the code for the other buttons aswell? Especially that of your fourth button.

Comment: Are you sure the method  GraphicsTools.getInstance()."somePanel" is returning the correct instances?

Comment: Yes I am, all the others panel works. Also, clicking a second time on the button did the trick, so it's not relate to GraphicsTools.

Comment: Does your fourth button lie in the same position (or would it if visible) as the button you want to click? Since you only make the panel "invisible" it might still be receptable...

Comment: Well, in fact it is -_-
But if the window is invisible, could the button be still receptable?

Comment: Not sure. Components usually also support a "setEnabled()" method. Maybe you could set that boolean to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be happening because of your mouse listeners. May be it is identifying the old button in your first click which is in the same location of new button (It is just my guess).

Change the mouse listeners to action listeners. For a button, it is sufficient if you have action listener.

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `revalidate()` on the frames as you change their viability.

Edit:

It could be something with the creation of the frames. Make sure you are calling 'pack()` on the frames.